# ETIMEOUT error with servicebus connection while using topics

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

I am creating 5 connections to servicebus and putting them in an array. Then as the new messages keep on coming I get one connection from the array and use them to send the message. When I start the service and run a load test it works fine. I leave the service ideal for sometime and run the same load test again, it starts having this error. `connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)`

I am not sure if it is a good way to cache the connection and reuse them, which would be causing this issue, or it is something else that causes this.

```
let serviceBusConnectionArray = [];
let executed = false;
let serviceBusService;
let count = 0;
let MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5;

class ServiceBus {

  static createConnections(){
    if(!executed){
      for(let i=0; i< MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++){
        serviceBusConnectionArray.push(azure.createServiceBusService(SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING).withFilter(new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter()));
      }
      executed = true;
    }
  }
  static getConnectionString(){
    ServiceBus.createConnections();
    if(count < MAX_CONNECTIONS){
      return serviceBusConnectionArray[count++];
    }else{
      count = 0;
      return serviceBusConnectionArray[count];
    }
  }

  static putMessageToServiceBus(topicName, message) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      serviceBusService = ServiceBus.getConnectionString();
      serviceBusService.sendTopicMessage(topicName, message, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          log.error('Error in putting message to service bus, message: %s', error.stack);
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve('Message added');
      });
    });
  }

}
```

I am not sure what route should I choose now, to resolve this timeout errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source code for [azure-sdk-for-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node), specifically these lines in order

- [servicebusservice.js#L455](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/serviceBus/lib/servicebusservice.js#L455)
- [servicebusservice.js#L496](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/serviceBus/lib/servicebusservice.js#L496)
- [serviceclient.js#L190](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/common/lib/services/serviceclient.js#L190)

The SDK is just performing REST requests to Service Bus via its [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch). So, I don't really think pooling those objects really help.

The timeout seems to be a genuine timeout at that point of time raised by the `request` npm module used by the SDK.

You could probably try the [newer SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/packages/%40azure/servicebus/data-plane) which uses amqp under the hood to connect to service bus. Note that this SDK is in preview.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am now using the newer SDK. So far it is going good.

Answer (score 0):

As PramodValavala-MSFT has mentioned about `@azure/service-bus` SDK in the other answer, major version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK(which was in the preview) depends on AMQP has been released recently.

Each instance of `ServiceBusClient` represents a connection, all the methods under ServiceBusClient use the same connection.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)